# INDEX MATCH Formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I recently took over this spreadsheet from someone who left the company. Formula in T column:

```
=INDEX(BFTable, MATCH(1, (UPPER(LEFT(ST, 2))=$E$1:$E$315)*
      (ProcessingDate>=$A$1:$A$315)*(ProcessingDate<=$B$1:$B$315)*
      (EffectiveDate>=$C$1:$C$315)*(EffectiveDate<=$D$1:$D$315)*
      ($AI3=$P$1:$P$315)*($F$1:$F$315="HM"),0),COLUMN()-COLUMN($T$2)+1)
```

Could someone explain to me what this formula is trying to do? What is ST? The output is the same with processing date in A column. There is no BFTable, although the tab name is BF.

Thanks,

SC

Comment: BFTable sounds like a named range. ST sounds like a named range as well but likely of only 1 cell with a string value in it. You can see if they have been allocated in Formulas - Name Manager.

Comment: https://spreadsheeto.com/index-match/ explains the MATCH() part

Answer (score 6):

The pieces `BFTable` and `ST` are probably named ranges.

What the formula does is look up in the range `BFTable` the row associated with the `MATCH(...)` part and the column given by `COLUMN()-COLUMN($T$2)+1`.

The `MATCH` section is a long conditional. It searches for the first case where all of the following conditions are true and returns the index of that row:

```
UPPER(LEFT(ST, 2))=$E$1:$E$315
ProcessingDate>=$A$1:$A$315
ProcessingDate<=$B$1:$B$315
EffectiveDate>=$C$1:$C$315
EffectiveDate<=$D$1:$D$315
$AI3=$P$1:$P$315
$F$1:$F$315="HM"
```

If they all return `TRUE`, then multiplying them together results in `1`, but if any of them returns `FALSE`, then multiplying them results in `0`, which won't match to `1` (the first argument of the `MATCH` function).

Comment: Good answer! Note that `UPPER` function is redundant here because the comparison with = is not case-sensitive. `LEFT(ST, 2)=$E$1:$E$315` would achieve the same thing